# FTP downloading in .NET

Tags: .net, ftp

Is there any built in functionality that enables downloading files from FTP in .NET?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting with .Net Framework 2.0: [System.Net.FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx)